# QSqlQuery::lastInsertId doesn't work with MS Access

Tags: c++, sql, qt, ms-access

I work with MS Access database (.accdb) and I need to insert some data and then get the last inserted ID. When I use `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId` method I see the following error:
`"QODBCResult::lastInsertId: not implemented for this DBMS" Error: ""`
I tried to use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` and similar expressions (`SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `IDENTITY_CURRENT`), but I get the same error.
Some time ago I used `SELECT @@IDENTITY` in VBA and that worked. So it's not about MS Access, but the driver?
Of course, I can write `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table`, but I'm not sure it's safe.
Is there a way to get the last inserted ID working with MS Access database?

#### UPD

**My code:**

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QString>

const QString DB_DRIVER = "QODBC";
const QString DB_DATABASE_NAME = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DSN='';"
"DBQ=C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\QtProjects\\Project\\DB.accdb";
const QString DB_USER_NAME = "root";
const QString DB_PASSWORD = "password";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(DB_DRIVER);
    db.setDatabaseName(DB_DATABASE_NAME);
    db.setUserName(DB_USER_NAME);
    db.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Database connection failed: " << db.lastError();
    }

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO Customers (Organization, Address, Contacts)"
                  "VALUES (:organization, :address, :contacts);");
    query.bindValue(":organization", "Some Organization");
    query.bindValue(":address", "Some Address");
    query.bindValue(":contacts", "Some contacts");
    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug() << "Error executing INSERT statement: " << query.lastError();
    }

    int newId = query.lastInsertId().toInt();
    qDebug() << QString("New ID is %1").arg(newId);
    qDebug() << "Last error: " << query.lastError();

    return 0;
}
```

**Full output:**
`"QODBCResult::lastInsertId: not implemented for this DBMS"   Error: ""`
`"New ID is 0"`
`Last error:  QSqlError("", "", "")`

Comment: It's hard to believe you get `lastInsertId: not implemented for this DBMS` when executing `SELECT @@IDENTITY`. Can you share your attempt where you tried that, and share the exact error?

Comment: @ErikA I've updated the post, you can have a look at my code and the debug output.

Comment: I still don't see `SELECT @@IDENTITY` anywhere in that code.

Comment: I think what your message is saying is that query.lastInsertId() is not supported for MS Access in the QODBC driver.  You'll need to create a second query that runs immediately after your INSERT that does a "SELECT @@IDENTITY" instead.  That should give you the last insert id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @user9601301's comment. I just needed run `SELECT @@IDENTITY;` in a separate query just after the `INSERT` query, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the syntax in your various unsuccessful examples.

SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table will work assuming ID is incremental;  your concern as to whether this is 'safe' I don't understand what is meant ....

If there is not a reliable incrementing ID field then typically one would add a date/time field with default value Now() which is of course incrementing - and use the Max of this field.